# Transparent BufferedImage shows with a black background while painted on a JLabel

Tags: java, swing, bufferedimage

I've got a BufferedImage which is created from a png file. When creating it I set the type to be TYPE_INT_ARGB which should give me a transparent image. When I use paintComponent inside a JPanel to paint the image, I get the image with a black background. I really need to get it transparent so any help will be useful. Here is the code for clarity:

```
public class ImagePanel extends JPanel {      

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image; 

    public ImagePanel() {
        this.image = null;
    }


    public void createImage(String fileName) {
        this.image = ImageUtilities.getBufferedImage(fileName, this);
        this.repaint();

     }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(this.image, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Here is how I load the image:

```
public class ImageUtilities {

/** Create Image from a file, then turn that into a BufferedImage.
*/

   public static BufferedImage getBufferedImage(String imageFile, Component c) {
       Image image = c.getToolkit().getImage(imageFile);
       waitForImage(image, c);
       BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(image.getWidth(c), image.getHeight(c),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
       Graphics2D g2d = bufferedImage.createGraphics();
       g2d.drawImage(image, 0, 0, c);
       return(bufferedImage);
   }
```

And one last thing to add is that this ImagePanel is inside another Panel, if that has any significance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will solve your problem, but:

- override paintComponent instead of paint (http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/closer.html)
- consider to use the newer javax.imageio API
- make sure the panel is not opaque (opaque = false)

Comment: The new IO API did the trick, though it would be nice to see a solution with the old method (if we assume the method I use is considered old), thanks :).

Answer (score 1):

Are you restricted to using an older version of Java? Try using ImageIO.read(fileName) to load the image file.

Comment: As I said in the previous comment, the ImageIO.read did it, now just of curiosity I'll try and poke to see how it can be done the old way. Thanks :)

Comment: No worries :) If trying the old way, try opening the image using Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage("myimage.png") and just draw the returned image directly to the component rather than creating a BufferedImage first.

Comment: ok, but will I be able to perform image processing techniques on the image opened that way. I am writing an app for a demonstration to show how is blurring, sharpening, etc. performed in Java.

Comment: No, you wouldn't be able to dry into the Image object, you'd have to create a BufferedImage if you wanted to draw into it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (i.e. setComposite()):

g2d.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver);
g2d.setPaint(backgroundColor);
g2d.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);